CPU stuck on 800MHz while on battery
Whenever I start my laptop on battery, CPU is stuck on 800MHz.
It can be fixed in Windows 11 using ThrottleStop to disable BD PROCHOT.
I already tried few scripts to disable it on Ubuntu 24.04.1, nothing worked.
I suspect it's Secure Boot, but I can't disable it.
Any idea how do fix it?
UEFI is literal garbage, no fix there
Specs:

Computer:             HP Pavilion Notebook 15-bc5xxx
CPU:                  Intel Core i5-9300H (Coffee Lake-H) Base 2400 MHz, Boost 3989 MHz
Motherboard:          HP 8640
Chipset:              Intel HM370 (Cannon Lake-H)
Memory (upgraded):    16 GB @ 1196 MHz, 17-17-17-39 (2x 8192 MB PC19200 DDR4 SDRAM - Micron 8ATF1G64HZ-2G3B1)
Graphics:             Intel UHD Graphics 630
Graphics:             NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, 3 GB GDDR5
Drive (upgraded):     WD Blue SN570 1TB, NVMe
OS (main):            Microsoft Windows 11 Home (x64)
OS (battery):         Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Maitenance log

Battery change:        October 2024
New thermal paste:      Q1 2024
Last dust cleaning:     5. November 2024
Drive upgrade:          January 2023
RAM upgrade:            End of 2023




Try this solution. You really need to be careful if you disable the PROCHOT bit, because it is your last line of protection for your processor. By default now MSR writes are disabled. You will need msr.allow_writes=on on your GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line. MSR writes can also be enabled manually on the fly with echo on | sudo tee /sys/module/msr/parameters/allow_writes

@DougSmythies wrmsr: pwrite: Operation not permitted.
Tried with echo on | sudo tee /sys/module/msr/parameters/allow_writes

Same error while using msr.allow_writes=on

Oh ya, I forgot that secure boot overrides. See the comments on an old answer of mine here
